# UIWebview - Text Cutting

Tags: html, ios

I am using the UIWebview for displaying the content. But I got the text cutting issue in web view. UIWebview content size get changes dynamically based on the image size and content.But that Webview frame is constant,

How to avoid it? Please refer the attachment image.

THanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you want to resize the web view to fit the content or is it not allowed to resize?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the delegate that indicates that the content is loaded completely then get the height by a javascript line of code, then adjust the frame of your uiwebview accordingly:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];
   [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, [output intValue])];
}
```

Enjoy :)